# Where to start when diagnosing linux crash issues?

Tags: linux, crash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an issue with a Raspberry Pi that crashes after a few hours.

It's booting from an SSD drive rather than an SD card. The power supply is giving a solid 5.16V and has the capability to supply about 6A. The SSD is plugged into a USB hub, which is then plugged into the Raspberry Pi, so the SSD is powered up before the Raspberry Pi starts and isn't drawing power from the Raspberry Pi, the socket to the Raspberry Pi has been modified to prevent back powering.

When I say crashes, what I find is that it can no longer be connected to, if connect a monitor etc, I will find the that task bar, Raspberry button, etc have all gone, all I have is the background and a mouse pointer that is responsive.

Regarding installed software, aside from what comes as standard, the only things I've installed/setup up are Plex Media Server, PlexAmp, and Samba. I have rebooted and stopped both the Plex items, left the machine logged in on SSH and after a few hours it had died (to SSH). It used to run fine for weeks on end.

I think I have previously managed to get a command prompt to appear with a keyboard short cut, but any commands like reboot or similar entered were ignored.

So what I would like to know is how I go about diagnosing the issue. I'm pretty sure someone is going to say look a the log files, but which one(s) and what to look for?

**UPDATE**: So I'm happy it's not a supply issue. I've ruled out any software that's been added, that's only the two pieces from Plex and even with their services stopped the issue still happens.

I've looked at syslog and messages log files, there is nothing obvious there, it's ticking away then just a big gap (in time) from the last entry to the next when the power is pulled.

Comment: Quick check first of all: Try read/write-testing the SD card in a different machine (not booting from it) - chances are, it has worn out.

Comment: Power supply stability and system temperature need to be monitored for that type of failure.  Do you have a list of what programs are running and/or what you are doing at the console when such failures occur?  The first step is to try to determine if this is HW or SW induced.